# How to create autocomplete in dynamic datagrid at particular column wpf using C# VS2010

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have created dynamic datagrid using c#, now i need to create autocomplete or autoextender in  particular column. Whenever i have create new row at runtime, the autocomplete or autoextender will be displayed on that particular Column. Please anyone can help me?

Thank u